# Error while deploying Qt5.10 App on linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-libraries

I'm trying to deploy a simple example on linux manually.

I copied the dependecies required by running

```
ldd ./binaryFile
```

inside the app directory

```
├── app.sh
├── lib
└── testApp
```

inside the lib directory I have

```
├──lib
  ├── plugins
  ├── qml
  └── other .so files from ldd
```

and then I run the bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`/lib
 export QML_IMPORT_PATH=`pwd`/lib/qml
 export QML2_IMPORT_PATH=`pwd`/lib/qml
 export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=`pwd`/lib/plugins/platforms
 #export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=0
 ./testApp
```

but I get this error

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs (from /home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms), linuxfb (from /home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms), minimal (from /home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms), minimalegl (from /home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms), offscreen (from /home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms), vnc (from /home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms), webgl (from /home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms), xcb (from /home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms).

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. ./app.sh: line 7:  1948 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./testApp
```

Even though the "xcb" plugin is inside the platforms directory

when I run it using

```
export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
```

I get this debug message

```
Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb") QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/zed/Desktop/testDep" ... QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/app.sh" QElfParser: '/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/app.sh' is not an ELF object "'/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/app.sh' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/testApp" "Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/testApp'" 
         not a plugin Cannot load library /home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/usr/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol
_ZNK15QPlatformWindow15safeAreaMarginsEv version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference) QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/usr/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol
_ZNK15QPlatformWindow15safeAreaMarginsEv version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference)" QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms/platforms" ... QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/platforms" ... This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms".
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

PS:
Qt Version : 5.10
Compiled on : Kubuntu 18.4
Tested on : Manjaro XFCE 17.1

Comment: Just doing `ldd myBinaryFile | grep xcb`, this my output:
`libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007fffeda13000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007fffed810000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007fffed608000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fffec9a2000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fffec77a000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fffec55f000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007fffec359000)`

Comment: Sorry for the format, I don't now how to put new lines in comment, you can copy/past in your text edit and format it.

Comment: I already copied all the files from ldd binaryFile to my lib folder, there's only one file with xcb in it
`libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f963ed93000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there's a mismatch between Qt Versions used on both machines

> `/home/zed/Desktop/testDep/lib/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/usr/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5:`
>   It was looking for that file in the OS libs not the libs I provided, I copied the required files from Kubuntu machine to the lib directory deployment machine and that fixed the issue